# Solucionar error has leaked IntentReceiver en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo una clase extendida de `BroadcastReceiver` en MainActivity.java lanzo el listener

```
registerReceiver(
        new ConnectivityChangeReceiver(),
        new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Me encuentro que cuando salgo de la app me muestra el siguiente error en el log:

> E/ActivityThread: Activity
>   com.webserveis.app.myconnection.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
>   com.webserveis.app.myconnection.ConnectivityChangeReceiver@32ad932e
>   that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()?
>                         android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.webserveis.app.myconnection.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
>   com.webserveis.app.myconnection.ConnectivityChangeReceiver@32ad932e
>   that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()?
>
> that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()

En `onStop()` me gustaria desregistrar el listener, pero no ser como implementarlo

Comment: desregistrar el receiver en onStop() funciona pero en realidad no es buena practica ya que siempre estaras recibiendo intents =(, agregue una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías de guardar tu `BroadcastReceiver` en una variable de tu `MainActivity` y en tu `onStop()` poner `unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);`

Debes de tener en cuenta que si pasases por el `onStop()`sin haber registrado el `BroadcastReceiver` previamente, te saltará una excepción.

Un saludo

Answer (score 5):

Cuando se implementa un [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), es importante saber que tenemos que registrar y desregistrar el receiver, pero 
**NO es buena practica cancelar el receiver en onStop() y esta es la razón,** la cual puedes ver en la documentación:

Cuando tu implementación requiere el registro en `onResume()` existe una consideración [importante](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

> Si está registrando un receiver en `Activity.onResume()`, debes anular
>   el registro en `Activity.onPause()`. (No recibirá intents cuando este en
>   pausa, y esto puede reducir innecesaria sobrecarga del sistema)

#### En cuanto a tu error:

> MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver

la documentación misma lo señala :

> No olvides cancelar el registro de receiver registrado en forma
>   dinámica mediante el método `Context.unregisterReceiver()`. Si se olvida
>   de esto, el sistema Android reporta un Leaked error. Por ejemplo, **si
>   registraste un receiver en `onResume()`** de su actividad, se debe
>   **cancelar el registro en el método `onPause()`**.

Por lo tanto :

> **En el método [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart()) generalmente se realiza el registro del receiver.**
>
> **En el método [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) generamente se realiza el desregistro del receiver.**

Agrego un ejemplo:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{

  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver ();

  //REGISTRA!
  public void onResume()
  {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);  

  }

  //CANCELA!
  public void onPause()
  {
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muy buenas Elena, si uso onResume y onPause, si se muestra otra app encima de la mia, se para el listener?

Comment: Buen día Webserveis. Se debe cancelar el receiver ya que esta en onPause() tu aplicación .

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente.